# How to use interface as parameter?

Tags: java, class, interface, ejml

I am using EJML and I want to use the class `LinearSolver_B64_to_D64`, which has the constructor: `LinearSolver_B64_to_D64(LinearSolver<BlockMatrix64F> alg)` with the interface `LinearSolver<BlockMatrix64F>` and the class has already implemented the `LinearSolver`.

**What I know:**
In general you create a interface, than you would implement that interface in a specific class.
I read about functions(in the specific class) that take the interface as a parameter, because that way your functions does not need to know something about the class.

**My question**:
I don't know how to initialise the class `LinearSolver_B64_to_D64`, because I don't know how to pass an interface as a parameter.

**Update:**
I tried the following code:

```
public class UseMatrixInterface{
    public UseMatrixInterface(){    
    }

    public void do1(){
        DenseMatrix64F a = new DenseMatrix64F(3,3);
        LinearSolver_B64_to_D64 ls = new LinearSolver_B64_to_D64(null); 

//it throws a nullpointer exeption. I assume, it is because i used null
//instead of the requiered parameter.
        ls.invert(a);
        a.print();
    }

    public void do2(){
        LinearSolver<BlockMatrix64F> lsD;
        LinearSolver_B64_to_D64 ls = new LinearSolver_B64_to_D64(lsD);
        //not working, because lsD cannot be initialised;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass an implementation of an interface as the actual value.

Comment: You need an instance of some class that implements the LinearSolver<BlockMatrix64F> interface.

Answer (score 1):

Just study javadoc; like starting here for the interface [LinearSolver](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/interfaces/linsol/LinearSolver.html).

And guess what: there is a section

*All Known Implementing Classes: AdjLinearSolverQr_D64, ...*

Go and pick the one that matches your needs; and create an **instance** of that class.

So the answer to your question is: you can't instantiate *interfaces*. Instead you look out for classes implementing the interface, and then you create an instance of such a class. Like in:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I am very new to programming, so reading the javadoc is also "difficult", but i tried `LinearSolver_B64_to_D64 ls = new LinearSolver_B64_to_D64(argument);` , but where "argument" ist should be the parameter for the interface and now i dont know how to create an instance, because the constructor requieres a interface.

Comment: Now i am very confused because an implementing class takes the implemented interface as a parameter??

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what's going on with this question and these answers.  LinearSolver_B64_to_D64 is a low level class for converting a linear solver for block matrices into the standard DenseMatrix64F.  You probably don't want to use that.

The Manual:

- [Solving Linear Systems](http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Solving_Linear_Systems)
- [LinearSolverFactory](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/factory/LinearSolverFactory.html)

LinearSolverFactory is the preferred way to create a new LinearSolver and hides most of the low level details from you.

Answer (score 0):

- create an instance of a class that implements the interface. Most likely the interfaces contract (the the JavaDoc of the interface) is simple enough to do this as an *anonymous inner class*

  ```
  LinearSolver<BlockMatrix64F> alg = new LinearSolver<BlockMatrix64F>(){
    // implement interface method(s) here
  }
  ```

then

- pass that object to the constructor of  `LinearSolver_B64_to_D64()`

  ```
  LinearSolver_B64_to_D64(alg);
  ```

Comment: I think you are on the wrong track. As I have outlined in my answer there are **plenty** of existing classes in that framework that implement that interface. Do you really think implementing a **Solver** for linear system is a small "here do implement anonymous interface" kind of activity?!

Comment: *"As I have outlined in my answer there are plenty of existing classes in that framework that implement that interface."* Then I don't get the point of your question. Do you really wan the community to decide which of that "plenty" implementations you should use?

Comment: No. I want **him** to figure what **he** should do. Do you really suggest that he **implements** a linear solver on his own; instead of **first** looking into the *existing* implementations, already available to him at his fingertips? Or in other words: if he would be asking for an implementation of the List interface, would you also suggest to implement that thing himself to him?